# Boost Process exit code of terminated process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

What should be a return code of a terminated process? I run `"bash -c \"while true; do true; done\""` and call [`terminate`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idm45477675615520-bb). In boost 1.65 it was `0`, now in boost 1.71 it is `383`.

Comment: `terminate` is documented to only signal the child process, I assume that the return code depends on what that process does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`exit_code()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idp39645760-bb) states:

> *The return value is **without any meaning** if the child wasn't waited for or if it was **terminated**.*

So it seems `exit_code()` isn't supposed to be called if the process is `terminate`d.

On Linux, an "exit code" of `383` (`0x17F`) means the process is still running. So it's worth trying to [`wait`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idm45360760454528-bb) for the process to finish before fetching its exit code.

There were a few changes in Boost.Process somewhere around version 1.71 which could explain the difference in behavior (for example, changed SIGTERM to SIGKILL), but according to `exit_code` documentation it was never OK to call it in combination with `terminate`.

Comment: Interesting, I do have a `wait` call. I just don't understand how can you get an exit code if the process is still running. One just excludes the other right?

Comment: See my updates. `exit_code()` is probably just a wrapper around `waitpid(... WNOHANG)`, which returns the exit *status*, which *may* contain an exit code.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732569/cant-get-segmentation-fault-exit-code-from-boost-child-process/57733210#57733210